# Jekyll YMAL nested list throws error: found a tab character that violate intendation

Tags: ruby, nested, jekyll

This is the list I'm using.

```
- name: Game1
  platforms: { win32, win64, linux64 }
  distribution:
    - name: here
      url: null
    - name: desura 
      url: http://www.desura.com/games/Game1
    source: https://github.com/name/Game1
  description: cg/games/Game1/description.html
  release: 2013-06-23
```

And this is the error it throws:

```
jekyll 2.2.0 | Error:  (C:/Users/User/jekyll-site/_data/games.yml): found a tab
character that violate intendation while scanning a plain scalar at line 39 {{- name: here}} column 13
```

How do I fix this list so it works?

Comment: you have to ensure that your text editor is replacing all the tabs by spaces. It will save you time debugging yaml files. dax is right.

Comment: for **Vi/Vim** users command `:set list` will help you find hidden tabs

Comment: Ivan's comment was very helpful! Solved my problem for sure!

Answer (score 31, accepted):

You have a tab character somewhere and yaml forbids them,  so the first thing to do ensure that there are no tabs.  There are several ways to do this, including removing every white space and replacing it with a space character.  Most editors have a way to visualize white space and whether or not it is a tab character.  There are also programs that convert tabs to space characters.  You can google for whatever suits your needs best.

After this, ensure that the indentation is correct and you should be okay.

Comment: Yup, that was the problem. Thank you very much!

Comment: This is popping up again in Azure DevOps land with the YAML in multi-stage pipelines. Adding the new message here in case it helps others: "While scanning a plain scalar, find a tab character that violate indentation"

Comment: Thank you! I had a vim addon that added tabs in which was causing the issue - edited my .vimrc file to remove this addon, which fixed the issue entirely. I was also editing a kubernetes config file so didn't have the file locally.